# Creating airflow variables and connections on MWAA using python requests (aws lambda)

Tags: aws-lambda, airflow, mwaa

I have a requirement to create airflow variables and connections on Amazon MWAA using a lambda function. Here is my python code to create variables:

```
r = requests.post(
  mwaa_webserver_hostname,
  headers={
    'Authorization': mwaa_auth_token,
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  },
  data="variables set KEY VALUE"
)
```

it is working fine for variables. But when I try to get or add a connection in the same way, I'm getting 500 error:

```
r = requests.post(
  mwaa_webserver_hostname,
  headers={
    'Authorization': mwaa_auth_token,
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
  },
  data="connections get <CONN_ID>"
)
```

`500 Server Error: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR for url: https://sjkdhfuweyr.<region>.airflow.amazonaws.com/aws_mwaa/cli`

What is missing here? Anything specific about the connection to be created in this approach?

Comment: Hi. So you found a solution for this problem ?