# Is there a way to import variables and connections to MWAA?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

I have a MWAA environment and I have to create another one by Terraform. The environment creation is not an issue, but the 'metadata' of my old enviroment. I want to import all variables and connections, programatically, but I haven't figured out so far.

I tried to change a few things in this [approach](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/samples-variables-import.html), using POST request to MWAA CLI, but I only get a timeout. And I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70896397/creating-airflow-variables-and-connections-on-mwaa-using-python-requests-aws-la) one.

Has anyone ever done this? I'd like to import variables and connections to my MWAA environment everytime I create it.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to copy the old MWAA variables into the new instance, you can refer to the following doc which contains all of the supported commands by AWS CLI https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/airflow-cli-command-reference.html.

The variables & connections set & get commands are available.

Unfortunately, not all commands are supported through the AWS CLI. Please note that you need to authenticate to AWS MWAA CLI, obtain the token, and then you will be able to execute the supported commands. Please refer to the following doc for more information https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/call-mwaa-apis-cli.html

Below are code snippets on how to obtain the CLI token and execute a command.

```
import boto3
import requests

AWS_MWAA_HOSTNAME_URL = ""

client = boto3.client('mwaa')


def generate_cli_token(mwaa_env_name):
    return client.create_cli_token(
        Name=mwaa_env_name
    )


def execute_mwaa_command(token, domain, command):
    res = requests.post(
        AWS_MWAA_HOSTNAME_URL.format(domain=domain),
        headers={
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        },
        data=command
    )
    if res.status_code == 200:
        return res.json()
    else:
        print(res.text)
        res.raise_for_status()
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks a lot for your help! But, when I try to make a post request, I wasn't getting any return... It was timing out. Do you have any idea that what could be happening?

Comment: Please share the full request-response so I can help

Comment: It doesn't give me a request-response... But I'll try to change the log levels.

Comment: Here a log: "HTTPConnectionPool(host='<url>', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f0c33bd3370>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))"

Comment: I believe the token you're passing is expired. Also, I need to see the request that you're trying to pass the full request

Comment: I'm using the code that you posted above. Creating the token at runtime, using the domain that is in MWAA config page and sent the command "dags list", just to test. Right now, I'm trying from my own machine and I set my IP in the MWAA security group. –

Comment: Please note that the token and the hostname are retrieved from the generate_cli_token method 'CliToken' & 'WebServerHostname', you don't need to whitelist your IP address in the security group you should be able to access the AWS MWAA CLI directly. Please make sure the that MWAA instance is publicly accessible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251046/discussion-between-luis-felipe-and-jamal-alkelani).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was getting a timeout and couldn't find out what was happening. To solve this situations I'll save my variables and connections in Secrets Managers and retrieve them at runtime with the DAG.